# Unable to connect from remote to Tomcat on compute engine

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine

I created a small Google Cloud compute engine with Debian Linux.  1 CPU 500M memory.

> root@instance-1:/opt/tomcat/tomcat/bin# ./version.sh Using
>   CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat/tomcat Using CATALINA_HOME:
>   /opt/tomcat/tomcat Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/tomcat/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /usr Using CLASSPATH:
>   /opt/tomcat/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M26 Server built:   Aug 2 2017
>   20:29:05 UTC Server number:  9.0.0.0 OS Name:        Linux OS Version:
>   4.9.0-3-amd64 Architecture:   amd64 JVM Version:    1.8.0_144-b01 JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

For my VM I've enabled http communication.

From the VM I can get to localhost:8080/manager (yes, I get a 401 permission but that is expected)

> root@instance-1:/tmp# wget localhost:8080/manager
>   --2017-08-22 17:22:04--  localhost:8080/manager Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1 Connecting to localhost
>   (localhost)|::1|:8080... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 302  Location: /manager/ [following]
>   --2017-08-22 17:22:04--  localhost:8080/manager/ Reusing existing connection to [localhost]:8080. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 302  Location: /manager/html [following]
>   --2017-08-22 17:22:04--  localhost:8080/manager/html Reusing existing connection to [localhost]:8080. HTTP request sent, awaiting
>   response... 401  Username/Password Authentication Failed.

From the outside world I go to MYIP:8080/manager but I get a timeout.

Gateway Timeout

Server error - server MYIP is unreachable at this moment.

Please retry the request or contact your administrator.

Comment: This might be better suited for https://superuser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com if you don't get any traffic/answers here.

Comment: Have you created a firewall rule for the port? Note that your service must listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of the VM's external IP.